# Apache tomcat server startup increase over 30000 ms in eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat

when i run my **JSP page on apache tomcat 7** in my eclipse, server output shows up in 30000ms or more some times it never starts up, at first output got in lessthan 700ms,

Any help or suggession on this problem...

sample output...

```
 NFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Mar 18, 2014 10:42:39 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [156] milliseconds.
Mar 18, 2014 10:42:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 18, 2014 10:42:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 18, 2014 10:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 30553 ms
```

Comment: are u running more then 1 application on the tomcat server?may be around 3 applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following 2 suggestions:

1)As I commented above check if more then one application is running on the same server.This could be the primary reason.May be 3 or 4 applications might be running once you start your tomcat service.

2)May be some library that you are using for your application is creating some problem,for example the library might be initializing some file storage or may be something else.For this you will have to debug and check your stacktraces.

Comment: very thankz.. man am only running my current jsp project as u said about case-1, i prefer case-2 as my problem i use external jars and also my JSTLjars of previous projects are creating traffic; i mean on running server jstl evaluations are also occurring unnecessarily..  any way could u suggest more precise solns...

Comment: am using **ApacheTomcat7.12**

Comment: @akcHitman dats a new version..check ur jars as i said..they might be creating some problem

Comment: okey.. jar may be problem, am using maven, when the jars not found in maven i manually dlod and put the jar in my **web-inf**->lib folder, and also jars are important if we mess with it then the whole project collapse.. any way thank u for u replay.. , ur answer accepted until a new effective soln is found...;-)